# Create Reusable Linq To SQL For Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I am working on a new project that needs to use `Linq To SQL`. I have been asked to create a generic or reusable `Linq to SQL` class that can be used to execute stored procedures.

In `ADO.Net` I knew how to do this by just passing in a string of what I wanted to execute and I could pass in different strings for each query I need to run:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myStoredProc", conn); // etc, etc
```

I am struggling with how to create something similar in `Linq To SQL`, if it is even possible.  I have created a `.dbml` file and added my stored procedure to it. As a result, I can return the results using the code below:

```
public List<myResultsStoreProc> GetData(string connectName)
{
   MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext (GetConnectionString(connectName));
   var query = db.myResultsStoreProc();

   return query.ToList();
}
```

The code works but they want me to create one method that will return whatever stored procedure I tell it to run.  I have searched online and talked to colleagues about this and have been unsuccessful in finding a way to create reusable stored proc class.

So is there a way to create a reusable `Linq to SQL` class to execute stored procs?

Edit:

What I am looking for is if there is a way to do something like the following?

```
public List<string> GetData(string connectName, string procedureName)
{
   MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext (GetConnectionString(connectName));
   var query = db.procedureName();

   return query.ToList();
}
```

I have reviewed the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic29) on `Linq To Sql` and these are showing the table in the `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> results = db.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(
   @"select c1.custid as CustomerID, c2.custName as ContactName
      from customer1 as c1, customer2 as c2
      where c1.custid = c2.custid"
);
```

I am looking for something very generic, where I can send in a string value of the stored proc that I want to execute.  If this is not possible, is there any documentation on why it cannot be done this way?  I need to prove why we cannot pass a string value of the name of the procedure to execute in `Linq To Sql`

Comment: Do you need to execute stored procedures that you may not have modeled in the .dbml file?  And are you wanting to return entities that are mapped in your .dbml?

Comment: they will most likely be mapped in the .dbml but I guess there could be a case where it wasn't

Comment: This is not the way LINQ to SQL is supposed to be used. You are working against the system. Try working as it is meant to be used.

Comment: @usr I didn't think it was supposed to be used this way. But the lead on the project wants to know if it is possible.  All of the code should be as reusable as possible

Comment: You already *have* a reusable way to call any stored procedure: Import it into the dbml and call it on the datacontext. Anyway, it is your decision.

Comment: @usr what they want is a way to pass into one method a string, etc to execute via Linq to SQL.

Comment: In my opinion this only makes sense if the result of the stored procedure does not matter. It would be useless to write generic code to execute sprocs, but do all kinds of specific stuff afterwards. You might as well make the call specific too.

Comment: Three cheers for DapperDotNet! http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

DataContext.ExecuteCommand is not quite what you are looking for, as it only returns an int value.  What you want instead is DataContext.ExecuteQuery, which is capable of executing a stored procedure and returning a dataset.

I would create a partial class for your DBML in which to store this function.

```
public List<T> GetDataNoParams(string procname)
{
   var query = this.ExecuteQuery<T>("Exec " + procname);

   return query.ToList();
}

public List<T> GetDataParams(string procname, Object[] parameters)
{
   var query = this.ExecuteQuery<T>("Exec " + procname, parameters);

   return query.ToList();
}
```

To call a stored procedure you would do:

```
GetDataNoParams("myprocedurename");
```

or

```
GetDataParams("myotherprocedure {0}, {1}, {2}", DateTime.Now, "sometextValue", 12345);
```

or

```
GetDataParams("myotherprocedure var1={0}, var2={1}, var3={2}", DateTime.Now, "sometextValue", 12345);
```

If you want to call procedures with no return value that is easy enough too, as I'm sure you can see, by creating a new method that doesn't store/return anything.

The inspiration came from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.90).aspx.

Comment: Is the DBML file going to tell the `ExecuteQuery<T>` method what `T` is so that the data can be mashed into object instances?

Comment: No, you tell it what it is when you call it.  My examples assume that you already have objects mapped to the return types for each stored procedure.  So if you have a stored procedure that returns customers and you have a customer object type then pass in Customer for T.

Comment: Gotcha. So we're not trying to `IQueryable`-ify stored procs and nothing needs to be omniscient.

Comment: Right, it's more like a standard DataAdapter.Fill command in that it just returns an enumeration of the data you want.  If you want to reconnect that data to the database to perform IQueryable operations that will take a bit more work, as in you would have to use the ID's to get the objects from the database again probably.  Though you can always just use Linq to objects if all you need to do is filter/sort/etc...

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the pointers with this, it has pushed me in the right direction. Still working out the kinks though.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer to your question is that you can grab the [`Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.connection.aspx) property of your `MyDataContext` and create and execute your own `SqlCommand`s just like you would in straight up ADO.Net.  I'm not sure if that will serve your purposes, especially if you want to retrieve entities from your LINQ to SQL model.

If you want to return entities from the model, then have a look at the [`DataContext.ExecuteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks for the direction for this, but can you provide additional info on how I could pass in a string with the name of the procedure I want to execute.

Comment: @bluefeet See Peter's answer, he's got a couple of decent examples.

Answer (score 0):

When we drop a Table or StoredProcedure in our .dbml file it creates its class which communicates with the data layer and our business logic.

In Linq to SQL we have to have the StoredProcedures or Tables present in the .dbml file otherwise there is no way to call a generic method in Linq to SQL for calling a stored procedure by passing its name to a method.

But in ADO.Net we can do it (like you know)

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myStoredProc", conn);
```